"Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto' in Expo SDK 50"
I'm encountering an issue after upgrading to Expo SDK 50. When I try to run my project, I get the following error:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'
   7 |   const cryptoObject =
   8 |     typeof crypto === 'undefined' || typeof crypto.randomUUID === 'undefined'
>  9 |       ? require('crypto')
     |        ^
  10 |       : crypto;
  11 |
  12 |   if (!cryptoObject?.randomUUID) {

It seems like the module 'crypto' is not being found or resolved properly. Here is the relevant code snippet:
import v35 from './lib/v35';
import { Uuidv5Namespace } from './uuid.types';
function uuidv4() {
    // Crypto needs to be required when run in Node.js environment.
    const cryptoObject = typeof crypto === 'undefined' || typeof crypto.randomUUID === 'undefined'
        ? require('crypto')
        : crypto;
    if (!cryptoObject?.randomUUID) {
        throw Error("The browser doesn't support `crypto.randomUUID` function");
    }
    return cryptoObject.randomUUID();
}
const uuid = {
    v4: uuidv4,
    v5: v35('v5', 0x50, sha1),
    namespace: Uuidv5Namespace,
};
export default uuid;
//# sourceMappingURL=uuid.web.js.map

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't found anything that works. Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Instead of using require have you tried the import() function so let crypto; try {  crypto = await import('node:crypto'); } catch (err) { console.error('crypto support is disabled!');}

maybe try deleting your node modules folder and doing a fresh install and fresh build
